# Does one need to close both NetworkStream and TcpClient, or just TcpClient?

Tags: c#, dispose, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm reading [the documentation on TcpClient.Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.close%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and noticed this:

> Calling this method will eventually result in the close of the associated Socket and will also close the associated NetworkStream that is used to send and receive data if one was created.

So, correct me if I'm wrong but this says that if one calls `Close()` on the `TcpClient` that the `NetworkStream` will also be closed.

So then why at the end of the code example are both `Close()` called?

```
networkStream.Close();
tcpClient.Close();
```

Would it be just as fine to only call `tcpClient.Close();`?

Comment: Yes, it isn't necessary.  Using tcpClient.Close() in that example isn't necessary either, the program terminates right after that :)

Comment: Prior to .NET 3.0, both the TcpClient and the underlying NetworkStream had to be explicitly closed.  Beginning in .NET 3.0, the underlying NetworkStream is closed when closing the TcpClient.  Close() and Dispose() on TcpClient are equivalent, with Close() adding some internal logging.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Responding to this question since no one else did so that I may accept an answer.

According to Hans, calling NetworkStream.Close() is unnecessary because TcpClient.Close() closes its underlying NetworkStream.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. See Vivien's answer. As noted there, the [doc for GetStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream.aspx) states `You must close the NetworkStream when you are through sending and receiving data. Closing TcpClient does not release the NetworkStream.`

Comment: However, the [doc for Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.close.aspx) states `Calling this method will eventually result in the close of the associated Socket and will also close the associated NetworkStream that is used to send and receive data if one was created.` I suspect the GetStream doc is out of date - that note has been there since .NET 2.0 (when it was still an issue).

Comment: I had the same question and found this post, the reference source code confirms that TcpClient.Close also calls Close of the NetworkStream, so this answer is correct.  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs,943f9db3a7511918

Answer (score 2):

NetworkStream and TcpClient implement IDisposable. So best practise in my opinion is to pack it into a using block, so you never need to close or dispose it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Closing the client does not close the stream, it's in the doc of the GetStream method.
For the reference, have a look to this discussion : [How to properly and completely close/reset a TcpClient connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425235/how-to-properly-and-completely-close-reset-a-tcpclient-connection)

Comment: [As Sam writes here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617127/does-one-need-to-close-both-networkstream-and-tcpclient-or-just-tcpclient#comment26031079_7623611), that note is out-of-date. It used to be necessary, but since .NET 3.0 it no longer is.

Answer (score -5):

You should Just do "TcpClient.Close()"
Or if you must, type both