# TcpClient does not flush writes

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I have this code to send `String` messages to a server. These messages are supposed to be sent separately, but the `Stream` of the `TcpClient` is sending the messages in one bug chunk after the `Stream` is closed.

What can I do to send separated messages with this code:

```
public void sendData()
{
    const int PORT_NO = 12900;
    const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";

    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
    try
    {
        client.NoDelay = true;
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        sendText(nwStream, "Text-1"); // Here is it supposed to send "Text-1"
        sendText(nwStream, "Text-2");
        sendText(nwStream, "Text-3");
    }
    finally
    {
        client.Close(); // But, all messages are sent here!
    }
}

private void sendText(NetworkStream nwStream, String text)
{
    byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
    nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
    nwStream.Flush();            
}
```

With this code the Server ends up receiveing: `Text-1Text-2Text-3` in one message and it is supposed to receive 3 different messages. What is wrong here?

Comment: Maybe the issue is on the server, not the client?

Comment: It looks like `TcpClient` implements `IDisposable`. Can you try altering the code so that you use the `using` syntax (e.g. `using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient) { /* send messages here */ }`) to see if that makes it behave? Shot in the dark, probably son't work, but thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: @UweKeim, why? could you be more specific?

Comment: @Scott His `try…finally` basically "simulates" a `using`.

Comment: @UweKeim ah right right.

Comment: Personally, I would use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see what is _really_ sent to the server.

Comment: You close/dispose the client, but you don't for the stream... any reason why you don't?

Comment: @JeffMercado When you close the `Client`, the `Stream` is automatically closed as well.

Comment: In addition, [here it is confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7623611/107625), that the stream is automatically closed.

Comment: The messages are "buffered". You can try to set the NoDelay property to false, but even then it's not a guaranteed. If you want to handle them as separate messages then you have to also send some kind of "split marker", in most cases you can start your message with a "header" which contains the size of the current message, then you know how many bytes you have to read for the current message. Or if you only want to send some strings you could place a special char at the end of the string to detect where the message/string ends.

Comment: Btw it can also happen that you send a message and in the next Read you only get some bytes of the message and you have to wait for multiple Read calls to get the full message, your client/server have to handle this situation also, otherwise you will suddently get weird "bugs" if you are not prepared for it.